# Add scalar to every non-zero entry of an Eigen::SparseMatrix

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I have a huge `Eigen::SparseMatrix`, and I would like to add a scalar to the nonzero entries in the matrix.

That is, if I had a matrix `A` with the values `_` signifies a `0` entry in the sparse matrix, i.e. it was never inserted.

```
    1 _ 2
A = _ 3 _
    4 5 6
```

I would like to do something like `A += 1` and arrive at

```
    2 _ 3
A = _ 4 _
    5 6 7
```

Where the zero entries are unaffected.

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am aware of three different approaches:

1. [Loop over all the non-zero values using an `InnerIterator`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSparse.html#title2)

   ```
   for (int k=0; k<A.outerSize(); ++k)
     for (SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(A,k); it; ++it)
       it.valueRef() += 1;
   ```

   This is a general method, which works in all cases, but may be slower than the other methods.
2. Using the [`coeffs`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseCompressedBase.html#a7cf299e08d2a4f6d6869e631e51b12fe) operator to obtain a 1D vector containing all the non-zero elements

   ```
   A.makeCompressed();
   A.coeffs() += 1;
   ```

   This method may be faster if the matrix was already in compressed form or you need the compressed format.
3. Accessing the raw data using [`valuePtr`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#ac2684952b14b5c9b0f68ae3bb8c517a6)

   ```
   typedef Map<const Array<double,Dynamic,1> > CoeffMap;
   CoeffMap coeffs(A.valuePtr(), A.outerIndexPtr()[A.outerSize()]);
   coeffs += 1;
   ```

   This method is probably the fastest method, but also the trickiest one and may be even slower on some machines due to performing a floating base operation on uninitialised data (see comment of chtz). If `A` is in compressed format, this approach is equivalent to method 2.

*Note that I have not benchmarked the different approaches.* The performance information is purely based on intuition. If you want to do it, be sure to use real sized matrices.

Comment: Just a minor remark: When using method 3 with an uncompressed matrix, you likely add to uninitialized values, which can cause a penalty on some machines (e.g., when non-finite or subnormal numbers are involved).

Comment: The second method is exactly what I needed. The matrix I'm using is 500000 x 20000 with only 1 in every 100 cells being filled. It fills the cells very very quickly, and I only need to perform the operation once. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to @m7913d's second answer: `coeffs()` is a very useful function in processing coefficient-wise math functions. Eigen documents only provided dense matrix based math calculation -> https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__CoeffwiseMathFunctions.html

For example, you can do sth like:

```
A.coeffs() = A.coeffs.exp();
```